# What's the effect/better one query OFFSET/LIMIT multiple times vs single query then read rows by rows

Tags: mysql, go

Which one is better (in most factors, eg. memory usage, scalability, in both cases: total data less than RAM or total data in database more than RAM):

query multiple times per 1k, until no more rows

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
  LEFT JOIN ... ON ... -- multiple times
ORDER BY created
LIMIT ?*1000, 1000
```

then

```
n := 0
for {
   rows, err := db.Query(sql, n) // assume this is prepared statement
   if err != nil { return nil, err }
   defer rows.Close()
   subtotal := 0
   for rows.Next() {
      err = rows.Scan( ... )
      if err != nil { return nil, err }
      subtotal += 1
   }
   if subtotal == 0 { break }
   n += 1
}
```

vs

one time query then scan it

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
  LEFT JOIN ... ON ... -- multiple times
ORDER BY created
```

then

```
rows, err := db.Query(sql) // assume this is prepared statement
if err != nil { return nil, err }
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
   err = rows.Scan( ... )
   if err != nil { return nil, err }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that a query that does `LIMIT 500000, 1000` will have to scan 501,000 rows to get the last 1000. LIMIT selects rows by position, not by value. So there's no way to use an index to skip right to the rows you want. Therefore it must start at the first rows, reading all of them until it gets past the offset you asked for.

So repeatedly paging through sets of rows with successive offsets is incredibly expensive, because each next query must re-read the thousands of rows it already read before. It's basically an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

P.S.: This won't work: `LIMIT ?*1000, 1000` because LIMIT does not take an expression. It takes only integer literals or placeholders. You'd have to do `LIMIT ?, 1000` and do the multiplication in Go code before passing the value.

Answer (score 1):

As Bill mentioned in his answer, OFFSET queries have well-documented downsides.

Selecting everything with a single query is fast as far as the database is concerned, but if you do not process the returned rows quickly, it uses the database connection for a long time, making it unavailable for anyone else. This can be a problem in a busy server, where idle database connections are often a scarce resource.

You have (probably) missed a third option that doesn't have either of those downsides: keyset pagination (aka. seek pagination). This works if foo has at least one UNIQUE NOT NULL column (i.e. a primary key), and created is indexed.

Keyset pagination is pretty well explained all over the web, but in short (assuming foo has a UNIQUE NOT NULL column named "id"):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM foo
  LEFT JOIN ... ON ... -- multiple times
WHERE (foo.created = X AND foo.id > Y) OR foo.created > X
ORDER BY foo.created, foo.id
LIMIT 1000
```

Here, X and Y are, respectively, the values of the created and id column in the last row from the previous query (omit the WHERE clause in the first query).

With this you retrieve consecutive pages in constant time. Depending on how rows are inserted into foo or any of the joined tables, you may miss rows or get duplicated rows when doing this (same as with OFFSET). If that's not an option, you have to stick to a single query.